# How to define or generate set of error code?

Tags: java, error-handling

As title, I have an requirement to define set of error code. The error code might be an unique string. It will be supposed to locate where and when the exception threw out.Just like oracle error code 'ORA-xxxxxx', so do we have a simple way to generate it?It might be built up by classname, method name or.....I can collect stack trace information from where the error occurs.Therefore anyone can help me or give me any strategy about this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to automatically generate this. You will have to sit down, write up the list of error codes and update all your error-handling code to work accordingly.

You may want to have a MyApplicationException class with getErrorCode() that handles consistent formatting and things like that, but figuring out which error code to use will be manual work.

I'd also argue that these "user-visible, well-defined error codes" do not replace the information you can get from a stacktrace (which a developer/support person would need to see).

Comment: Yes, I agree what you said, this should be manual work. But my colleague told me that error code should be unique. If place or time changed, it would be generated differently.So I guess if i could generate it via stacktrace information like methodname, classname, line etc. Thus the defination of error looks simple.